# ListBox with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, listbox

I am data binding a IQueryable collection of Suppliers to a listbox as follows in my page load event...

```
        SupplierRepository sr = SupplierRepository.GetInstance();
        lbSuppliers.DataSource = sr.FindAll();
        lbSuppliers.DataTextField = "SupplierName";
        lbSuppliers.DataValueField = "SupplierID";
        lbSuppliers.DataBind();
```

But for some reason when I try to get the selectedvalue from the list box as follows it's returning null, even though I can see the values in the html source view at runtime.

```
lbSuppliers.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Seems a very basic problem, but I am stuck. Is this because I am using a EF collection for the data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you binding every `PageLoad`? If you are, then the `SelectedItem` will disappear.

Try wrapping the DataBinding code in an `If (!IsPostBack)` block.